# Что не так с параметрами функций?

Tags: python, shutil

Использую модуль shutil и в функции shutil.copy2  os.path.join() ругается на аргументы:

```
import os
import time
import shutil

class FileSorter:

    def __init__(self, folder_name):
        self.folder = folder_name
        self.full_time = None
        self.output_path = None
        self.path = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

        def sorting(self):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(self.path, "icons_by_year"), exist_ok=True)
    for i in os.walk(top=os.path.join(self.path, self.folder)):
        for file in i:
            secs = os.path.getmtime(file)
            self.full_time = time.gmtime(secs)
            if os.path.join(self.path, "icons_by_year", str(self.full_time[0]), str(self.full_time[1])):
                shutil.copy2(src=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), file),
                             dst=os.path.join(self.path, "icons_by_year", str(self.full_time[0]),
                                              str(self.full_time[1]), file))
                #  после обьявления self.path функция ругается на неправильные аргументы, хотя пути вроде верные
                # TODO В join нужно передавать строки или пути, а передаётся  число.
            else:
                os.makedirs(os.path.join(self.path, "icons_by_year", str(self.full_time[0]), str(self.full_time[1])))
                shutil.copy2(src=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), file),
                             dst=os.path.join(self.path, "icons_by_year", str(self.full_time[0]),
                                              str(self.full_time[1]), file))
folder = FileSorter(folder_name='icons')
folder.sorting()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: раз ругается на аргументы, значит, нужно поменять аргументы.

Comment: покажите ваше 'ругается'. скопируйте полный текст ошибки и добавьте в ваш вопрос.

Comment: а что непонятно в тексте ошибки? Если будет написано "нужно ввести число, а не букву", тоже побежите в интернет за помощью?

Answer (score 1):

```
if os.path.join(self.path, "icons_by_year", self.full_time[0], self.full_time[1]):
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    shutil.copy2(src=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), file),
                 dst=os.path.join(self.path, "icons_by_year", str(self.full_time[0]),
                                  str(self.full_time[1]), file))                  
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Вот вы когда используете `shutil` преобразовываете `self.full_time[0]` в строку. А когда чуть выше проверяете в `if`, то не преобразовываете, у вас там `int`. Скорее всего `os.path.join` ругается именно на это. С `self.full_time[1]` - тоже самое. Преобразуйте в строку через `str(...)` оба эти значения, как вы это делаете ниже.

Про вторую ошибку я что-то не разобрался, сначала написал, потом удалил.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Заметил это. преобразовал, вроде бы та ошибка ушла, но желтое выделение так никуда и не пропало